# What does the word しゅき mean in the context of this comic?

Tags: meaning, translation, pronunciation, manga, slang

I'm reading [this comic](https://imgur.com/gallery/Nil6K1S), and the words しゅき appear on the last page (page 4 of 4) but I don't know what it means in this context and without the proper kanji.

[image]

I feel like the words I know that can be pronounced as しゅき don't fit the bill. Is it maybe slang? An abbreviation? A name? Or maybe it's a common word but I'm unaware of how it flows with the sentence?

Answer (score 6):

It's a "slurred" version of 好き. In this context it expresses he was too overwhelmed to pronounce it well, but it's typically used by a female speaker in "lovey-dovey" scenes of manga. Variations include ちゅき, だいしゅき, [いっぱいちゅき](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B1%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%82%85%E3%81%8D), etc.

Comment: It should be mentioned it is originally a baby word. す turns into しゅ/ちゅ as in でしゅ/でちゅ for です. Another version of 好き often used these days on the internet is すこ, which is not for babies and not related to love. It is just used to say 好き in a funnier way. Its imperative is すこれ.